# Unit Testing Xamarin Forms & Parse

Tags: .net, xamarin, nunit, parse-platform, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and Parse and would like to unit test my code. Unfortunately when I reference the Parse dll and start adding Parse objects I get the following runtime error...

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System,
>   Version=2.0.5.0

Comment: Hello friend. Did you manage to work around this issue when had it two years ago?

Comment: check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824812/xamarin-forms-system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-find-file