# how to fix Xamarin.forms System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I am using **xamrin.forms**, and I am trying to access file and read it.

I have lastusername.txt as text file and I set the build action for it as "Content", actually I am trying to read file as the following:

```
  var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "lastusername.txt");
    if (filename != null)
           return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);//error occurred here 
    else
           return "";
```

I get the following Error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file

Comment: You might want to double check what happens with files that you include when building. I don't think they will be placed in the folder you're trying to access here

Comment: right ..so i think i need to change this  Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal ,I  am searching about which one refer to files on my project ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your file within the Android **Assets** folder and assign it with a build type of "AndroidAsset".

Since your app's assets are read-only, you can then read it via the `AssetManager`, saving (copy) it somewhere else if it does not exist (i.e. the first time the app is run):

```
var fileName = "MyAssetBasedFile.txt";
if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(CacheDir.Path, fileName)))
{
    AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open(fileName)))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(CacheDir.Path, fileName), append: false))
        sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
string content;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(CacheDir.Path, fileName)))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
Log.Debug("SO", content);
```

The next time the app runs you will pick up the one in your cache dir.

Comment: @MohamadMahmoud Your app bundle is READ-ONLY. You will need to check if it exists in your cache directory (or where ever you expect it to be), if it does not exist there, read it from your app's Assets, and write it your cache directory. On the next app run you will find the updated version and thus not "copy" the initial one from Assets.

Comment: good idea , could you please update your answer and add some help code line .. thanks

Comment: i am working with content  file (txt file with build action =  content) it is readable and writerable the problem was because i need to write it before read it again  .